# Configure Mailgun API For Emails in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, mailgun, suitecrm

I need to configure Mailgun for sending emails in SuiteCRM using a Campaign. I have completed the domain registration and I now need to integrate Mailgun with SuiteCRM.

Where should I add the API key? Is it possible to integrate this API with SuiteCRM?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get SMTP credentials from your Mailgun dashboard (Under "Domains") and use them for suiteCRM. This is what I'm doing; do you need more/different integration?